# How can i make parallel or concurent API calls?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, retrofit2, gson

I am building an Android app (my first app actually) and it's about getting similar tracks to the one you searched for. I am using retrofit2 with rxJava and gson for my calls.
For each track i found i add the corresponding image provided by the response in an imageview, but this image is not the actual album image, it's just an image of the band. I want to have the album image which i can get from the API if i do an album search.

So is there a way to make a API call that returns the album info for each track without losing to much time loading? I want these calls to happen in parallel with each other so as to be less visible to the "user" (me).

This is the code that i use to search for the similar tracks:

```
private void loadSimilarTracks() {
    String mbid = selectedTrack.getMbid();
    String artist = selectedTrack.getmArtist();
    String track = selectedTrack.getName();

    searchService = new LastFMSearchService();

    Flowable<List<TrackSimilar>> fetchDataObservable = null;
    if(!mbid.equals("")) {
        fetchDataObservable = searchService.getSimilarTracks(mbid);
    }
    else{
        fetchDataObservable = searchService.getSimilarTracks(artist, track);
    }


    mCompositeSubscription.add(fetchDataObservable
            .timeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<List<TrackSimilar>>() {

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<TrackSimilar> tracks) {

                    mTracks = tracks;
                    similarTrackAdapter.setTrackList(tracks);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "API CALL ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    resultsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            })
    );
}
```

P.S i am using the lastFM api for my info.
Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, one thing that you can do is that you can segment your code into multiple functions instead of a single one and run them as separate threads.

One function that makes api calls to search for similar tracks and other to get the image and trust me that significantly improves the response. Hope it helps..